# ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I have problem, when trying to connect to Oracle Database XE via listener:

```
 sqlplus system/my_password@XE
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

I use Ubuntu 12.10 and Oracle Express Edition 11g.

My main goal to connect java + oracle db with jdbc, but there i get the same error.

Here are my listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = watson)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

and tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = watson)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

and

```
lsnrctl service

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 04-FEB-2014 17:01:44
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Your listener seems to have started fairly recently; if that was after the database started it might not have registered, though it should retry frequently. But to check, if you `alter system register` does your service appear in the `services` list? If not, do you have the `local_listener` parameter set? If not that defaults to the server's network name - so does that resolve to the same IP as `watson`, particularly if yout server has multiple IP addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your database is failing to register even when the listener has been running for a while, it sounds like your `local_listener` parameter isn't explicitly set, so your database is trying to register [on a default address](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams116.htm); and since it's failing to register, whatever address it's using doesn't seem to be the same one the listener is on.

Assuming `watson` is resolving to a useful external IP address, which is probably the case if you're able to get that TNS error from outside your box, you can tell the database to use the same address to register:

```
alter system set local_listener = '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=watson)(PORT=1521))' scope=memory;
alter system register;
```

If that works and `lsnrctl services` now shows `XE` and you're happy with it, you can change the `memory` to `both` and re-execute [so it persists across the next DB restart](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_2014.htm#SQLRF53147).

Alternatively, if you've only tried connecting within the same box, `watson` might be resolving to something unhelpful, like 127.0.0.1 if it's set to do that in your `/etc/hosts`; or your `/etc/hosts` address might not agree with your DNS entry. You can change the `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` to the 'right' FQDN or IP address instead, as long as that matches whatever your database thinks is the network name.

Answer (score 5):

I had to restart my OracleServiceXE service in windows services and it was working again.

Answer (score 0):

The tnsnames.ora is fine, it is used for the sqlplus client.
The listener.ora is not good. You are missing the XE service when you type lsnrctl service
Hard to believe you have to setup listener.ora to install Oracle express.

Here is a example from my testing VM.

```
Service "PEXPROC" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PEXPROC", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "ocmdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ocmdb", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:29 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

My sample segment in listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER_OCM =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ocmdb)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1)
      (SID_NAME = ocmdb)
    )
  )
```