# ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor for existing service

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tnsnames

I know that this is a pretty popular problem, and I had run into it several times before but were able to resolve it but not this time.

I had made sure that I'm using the correct service name by running

```
SQL> select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XE
```

My tnsnames.ora has the XE service name:

```
XE =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVER = DEDICATED)
       (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
     )
   )
```

When I start the listener, it appear to recognize the service:
    [root@aa-axm admin]# lsnrctl start

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 09-OCT-2015 12:58:28

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/aa-axm/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE))  (SERVICE_NAME=XE))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(SERVICE_NAME=XE))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                09-OCT-2015 12:58:28
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/aa-axm/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE))(SERVICE_NAME=XE))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(SERVICE_NAME=XE))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

And yet, I'm still getting that blasted error

```
[root@aa-axm admin]# sqlplus SYSTEM/**********@XE

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri Oct 9 12:58:36 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

What am I missing? TIA

Comment: Is your DB's `local_listener` init parameter set? [You might be having this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21555172/266304). (Not really relevant, but why are you doing this as root?)

Comment: What is the location of the tnsnames.ora file you've quoted? are you trying to connect to the DB from the same machine?

Comment: The tnsnames.ora is located in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin, where ORACLE_HOME/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin. Yes, I'm attempting to connect from the same machine.

Comment: And your `local_listener` setting? If that is null, does `aa-axm` resolve to 127.0.0.1 or something else? If you want to only be able to connect locally then change the `local_listener` (as in the linked answer); otherwise change the address the listener is on. They need to match, either way.

Comment: I went with localhost alter system set local_listener = '(address=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope=memory;

Comment: I reconfigured the local_listener using localhost which I used alsoi n listener.ora and tnsnames.ora. After restarting the listener I see that is names default service XE but starts only PLSExtProc. 'lsnrctl service' also lists only PLSExtProc

Answer (score 2):

I had it finally resolved by doing

```
alter system set local_listener='XE' scope=both;
alter system register;
```

thanks to [Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole) for setting me on the right path.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent multiple hours to find an answer for this.