# XE service not found in Oracle services list

Tags: oracle11g, centos, centos7, oracle-xe

something strange happened to my CentOS VM. Everything was working fine until I made a restart and the Oracle XE service is not active anymore. I checked with: `service oracle-xe status` and this is the result:

```
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                04-APR-2017 11:31:50
Uptime                    0 days 16 hr. 13 min. 43 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ldap1/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=::1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

In services summary there is only `PLSExtProc` service listed. No XE service. Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like your database hasn't been started yet; it will attempt to register with the listener when it does. (It's also possible it's trying to register against an invalid address, e.g. because your server's IP address changed, though the listening ports suggest that shouldn't be a problem; but you'd have to see what the `local_listener` initialisation parameter is set to to verify that).

Comment: I think you are right. The IP address has changed. I will reply again as soon as I will figure this out. Please make your comment as a response, so that I can mark it as solution if everything goes fine

Comment: It may be [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553557/266304), depending on what's actually wrong.

Comment: You are right, I was following that one. I just voted to close this as a duplicate to the link you shared.