# create a database with oracle SQL developer failed,error: ora-12505

Tags: database, oracle

I recently installed oracle express (**left everything by default**) on my machine , when I want to create a database with SQL Developer it s failed with this error:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

I tried to change this parameters and changed in listener.ora and tnsnames following research on google but nothing worked . like : Host= localhost instead of my computer name , and  SID=xe .

database creation parameters :

```
Connection Name :  system
Username        :  system
password        :  **
Hostname        :  localhost
SID             :  xe
```

any helps thank you .

Comment: You are adding a connection, not creating a database. The error means you are reaching the listener, so the hostname/IP and port are OK (or were before you changed them *8-). Did you try with service name (rather than SID) set to XE?

Comment: yes already tried that , same error

Comment: Well,it won't be the same error, but if it now says ORA-12514 and the service isn't recognised either, then either the database isn't running or it hasn't been able to register with the listener - probably the latter, particularly if you are able to connect through SQL\*Plus. If you've changed the file config to use localhost you may need to tell the DB that too - if that is the case, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21553557/266304) (but use 'localhost' instead of 'watson'). And if you're using localhost then you won't be able to connect from anywhere except your PC, which may be OK.